# c# StreamWriter input string is not the same on the output string on the file

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, streamwriter

I am having a problem with my StreamWriter. I'm using Visual Studion 2010 and 2015, .NET Framework 4.0. Here is the sample of my Code to write a log file:

```
using (StreamWriter swErr = new StreamWriter(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Logs/") +
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log", true, Encoding.Default))
{ 
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg))
        swErr.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss " + errMsg));
    if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
        foreach (Mandrill.EmailResult x in result)
        {
            stat = string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}",
                        x.Id, x.Email, x.Status, x.RejectReason ?? "-"
            );
            Console.WriteLine(stat);
            swErr.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss " + stat));
        }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errMsg) || (result != null && result.Count > 0))
        swErr.WriteLine("---");
}
```

For some reason, here is the sample Expected vs Actual output of this code:

```
Expected OUTPUT:

10:10:02 e7424f10d1ee431fb69d9014265b278a | tito.genovajr@paramount.com.ph | Sent

----------



ACTUAL OUTPUT

10:10:02 e742431091ee4313b6999014265b278a | AiAo.A.D.enovajr@para10ounA.co10.p10 | SenA

----------
```

For some reason I do not know it converts some character to a random number or letter(s). I tried removing the parameter of StreamWriter for Encoding, also tried passing `Encoding.ASCII` and `Encoding.UTF8` but it's still the same.

I think my syntax is OK and handled the disposing of the StreamWriter properly.

I hope anyone can help me regarding this.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have special characters in input?

Comment: One more thing, if you try using File.WriteAllText(), what is the output?

Comment: I do not have any special characters. Also, the file loaded on the path on the streamWriter is either not existing or existing. I'll try using what you suggest and see what happens.

Comment: StreamWriter does not have a bug.  Encoding can't explain why 'm' is replaced by '10'.  Disk corruption never inserts text.  So that just leaves a corrupt `x` object.  Use the debugger.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant. I tried refactoring my code and found out why it's writes like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones who will encounter this question. I'm really sorry for my stupidity but this is a syntax error. The error message is included on the string formatting of the date.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss" + errMsg);
```

This must be:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + errMsg;
```

Hope any other person would not encounter this.